# where are the 42 header bytes?

Tags: ros, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went through the code carefully, I can't figure out where are the 42 header bytes.

According to the doc for the 32E, the data packet should start with a 42 bytes header, followed by 1200 bytes of data (block + encoder + points), terminated by 6 status bytes.

In the pcap reading code, those are discarded (input.cc line 269). I cannot find any trace of it in the `InputSocket` code. Can anyone explain?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203897/where-are-the-42-header-bytes?/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2015-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The IP and UDP headers are not returned by a `recvfrom()` on a UDP socket.

see: http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=4656

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1